# WIX Sideloading fails to deploy dependencies appx

Tags: powershell, wix, win-universal-app, appx

I am deploying an appx package using WIX following this tutorial:

http://nicholasarmstrong.com/2014/08/sideloading-windows-8-apps-with-wix/

When I run the resulting setup on a freshly installed Windows 10 PC, the logs provide me with the following error:

```
    CAQuietExec:  Found dependency package(s):
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:10:376]: Closing MSIHANDLE (78) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:10:423]: Creating MSIHANDLE (79) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  C:\Program Files (x86)\SoftwareSetup\Software_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:10:423]: Closing MSIHANDLE (79) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:10:423]: Creating MSIHANDLE (80) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  C:\Program Files (x86)\SoftwareSetup\Software_Test\Dependencies\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:10:423]: Closing MSIHANDLE (80) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:283]: Creating MSIHANDLE (81) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  Add-AppxPackage : Deployment failed with HRESULT: 0x80073CF3, Package failed updates, dependency or conflict 
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Closing MSIHANDLE (81) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Creating MSIHANDLE (82) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  validation.
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Closing MSIHANDLE (82) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Creating MSIHANDLE (83) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Closing MSIHANDLE (83) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Creating MSIHANDLE (84) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  Windows cannot install package Software because this package depends on another package that couldn't be found. This 
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Closing MSIHANDLE (84) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Creating MSIHANDLE (85) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  package requires minimum version 1.0.23430.0 of framework Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0 published by CN=Microsoft 
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Closing MSIHANDLE (85) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Creating MSIHANDLE (86) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US to install; the frameworks with name 
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Closing MSIHANDLE (86) of type 790531 for thread 2832
MSI (s) (94!10) [18:07:17:298]: Creating MSIHANDLE (87) of type 790531 for thread 2832
CAQuietExec:  Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0 available to the user are Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23430.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.
```

When I do a manual deployment (doubleclick the AddAppxPackage powershell command), the deployment finishes without any problems. It seems that running this same powershell script through the Wix installer does not deploy the dependencies in the right manner, even though the dependencies are included with the installer.

Any ideas?